# Convert escaped HTML to raw HTML

Tags: html, sql, excel, excel-formula

I have data in the SQL Server Management Studio where description is stored in the below format (escaped html):
    &lt ; pre &gt ; &lt ;div &gt ;&lt ;p &gt ;&lt ;font

```
<pre><div><p><font>
```

I need this to convert to raw HTML format which I'm exporting to Excel. I'm uploading into a blog which can convert only the raw HTML to visual text. Would be glad if someone could help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming escaped HMTL is in cell A1, try this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&lt;","<"),"&gt;",">")
```

Comment: Thanks Ii'' try to replace them with the raw html characters